# Using C# to Load Excel Name Manager

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I was trying to use C# loading Excel Name Manager, however, the name contains invalid chars like "\0". How to deal with that?  I can't even 'var name = pkg.Workbook.Names;'.

Error Like this: System.ArgumentException:“Name \0 contains invalid characters”

```
using (ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage(filePatha))
        {
            var name = pkg.Workbook.Names;
            foreach (ExcelNamedRange excelNamedRange in name)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"IsNameHidden:{excelNamedRange.IsNameHidden}\n" +
                                  $"Name:{excelNamedRange.Name}\n" +
                                  $"Address:{excelNamedRange.Address}\n" +
                                  $"Formula:{excelNamedRange.Formula}\n" +
                                  $"Text:{excelNamedRange.Text}\n" +
                                  $"Value:{excelNamedRange.Value}\n" +
                                  $"FullAddressAbsolute:{excelNamedRange.FullAddressAbsolute}\n" +
                                  $"---------------------------------\n");

                

            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: Google shows a number of hits about a bug in epplus that disallows valid characters. Are you on the latest version of epplus?

Answer (score 0):

I read the EPPlus class 
Seems that I can't use ExcelNamedRangeCollection if there are any invaild name in the Name Manager. I've already solved this with OpenXML.

```
    /// <param name="Name">The name</param>
    /// <param name="Range">The range</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ExcelNamedRange Add(string Name, ExcelRangeBase Range)
    {
      if (!ExcelAddressUtil.IsValidName(Name))
        throw new ArgumentException("Name contains invalid characters or is not valid.");
      if (this._wb != Range._workbook)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The range must be in the same package. ");
      return this.AddName(Name, Range);
    }
```